# Using Perl's Tk debugger, how can I set a breakpoint in my Perl library?

Tags: perl

I have a large Perl script that is broken into several Perl libraries.  In [the Perl Tk debugger](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::ptkdb), I'd like to be able to set a breakpoint in one of the library files.  The only way I know how to set a breakpoint in `ptkdb` is to navigate to the line in the source code pane.  However, that source code pane only has the top level Perl script.

How can I set a breakpoint in my library?

FYI, I know I can use Eclipse with a perl plugin to accomplish this task, but I'd like to do it in `ptkdb` because the Eclipse setup time is extensive.

Comment: Try File/Open. You will need to extend window as scrolling is missing.

Comment: [See this question/answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920477/how-to-set-breakpoint-on-a-particular-file-in-perl-program). It is now my preferred way to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about *.pm files:

file -> open -> select the module you want -> select the line you want && ctrl+b.