# How to set breakpoint on a particular file in Perl program?

Tags: perl

My Perl program looks like:

```
foo/
foo/bar/
for/bar/test.pm
foo.pm
foo/bar.pm
test.pl
```

and use `perl test.pl` to start the program.
I want to debug a sub in foo/bar/test.pm. How to set a breakpoint on that sub?

Comment: I'm not satisfied with the answer provided.  What is the `b [ln]` syntax required to break at a particular line in a particular file?

Comment: "f filename" in the debugger window will show the full path. then copy that path and write "b full_path/test.pm:line_number"

Comment: @nurp After `f filename`, you can just use `b line_number`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To debug a perl script, use the `-d` switch to invoke the debugger.

```
perl -d test.pl
```

Within the debugger you can use `b <line no>` to set a breakpoint in the current file. Sometimes it is a hassle to set a breakpoint in a file that hasn't been loaded yet or that was loaded a long time ago, so you can also put the line

```
$DB::single = 1;
```

anywhere in any perl program, and the debugger will break immediately after it executes that line. This is also a good way (the only way?) to set a breakpoint in code that will be run at compile time.

Comment: Worth noting, the 'f' command in the debugger will switch to viewing a filename, as in 'f /Path/To/Module.pm'; the file must be already loaded. Then you can set a breakpoint, not only at the entry point of a subroutine, but at any valid line in that file.

Comment: '$DB::single = 1;' line working for any one? It's not stop the control i guess

Comment: We can use <>; line to stop the control (but not able to see any values for a variable). print Data::Dumper::Dumper($variable); line helps to print the values

Comment: I'm using perl since 1995 and NEVER came across `$DB::single = 1;` I'm extremely thankful for that hint!

Answer (score 18):

Just use the fully qualified name of the sub as the argument to `b`:

```
b foo::bar::test::subname
```

Example:

```
$ perl -d -e'use CGI; CGI->new'
...
main::(-e:1):   use CGI; CGI->new
  DB<1> b CGI::new
  DB<2> r
CGI::new(.../CGI.pm:337):
337:      my($class,@initializer) = @_;
  DB<2> q
```

Comment: This is the actual answer to the OP's question. 

(I already knew this, and was in fact looking for the information given in the other answers.)

Comment: How do I break at a particular LINE of the package?

Comment: @snoopyjc Put `$DB::single = 1;` on that line

Comment: @ikegami Thanks but I meant without changing the source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can enter `f Module.pm` to tell the debugger to look at that particular module.  Once you've done that, `b line_number` will stop at that line in `Module.pm`.

Once the original script has passed `use Module`, then `b subroutine` will stop at that subroutine.  The only catch here is that you can't make your first two debugger commands `f Module.pm; b subroutine` because when the script begins, it hasn't passed `use Module`, so Module.pm hasn't loaded yet, which means that perl can't see that `Module.pm` has `subroutine`.